# Rulings of One Sheet Hyperboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $M$ be a hyperboloid of one sheet satisfying $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. Show that $x(u,v)=(\frac{uv+1}{uv-1},\frac{u-v}{uv-1},\frac{u+v}{uv-1})$ gives a parametrization of $M$ where both sets of parameter curves are rulings.

I have been working on this for quite a while but have not been able to write $x(u,v)$ with the above parametrization as a ruled surface in $u$. I tried letting $u=\tan(\varphi)$ and $v=\tan(\psi)$ but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**: First you should check that the points given by the parametrization do in fact lie on the hyperboloid. Next, you want to see that the $u$- and $v$-curves are in fact lines. You need to do some algebraic manipulations with the rational functions (like "long division"). It will help to fix $v=v_0$, say.

Comment: That was what confused me the most. Say a u-curve is $x(u,v_0)$. How do I long divide $x(u,v)$ coordinate by coordinate? For instance, I cannot find a real-valued function $f(u)$ and a real number $A$ such that $$\frac{uv+1}{uv-1}=f(u)+A\frac{uv_0+1}{uv_0-1}.$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure where that equation came from. You should be considering $\dfrac{uv_0+1}{uv_0-1} = 1 + \dfrac 2{uv_0-1}$.

Comment: Isn't a ruled surface $x(u,v)=\alpha(u)+v\beta(u)$ where $v\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\beta(u)$ being a ruling by definition? So if we want to show a $u$-curve is a ruling, then we should find the corresponding $\alpha(u)$ and constant $v$. Did I misunderstand the question or the definition?

Comment: You're correct, as far as the *standard* parametrization goes. But there's nothing that says that you have to move along the rulings with constant speed. Any reasonable function will do in the place of $v$ in that formula.

Comment: Ted, do you know a traditional source for this parametrization? I cannot seem to get it as stereographic projection around one of its points. This relates to a continuing interest in an 1897 book by Fricke and Klein, which may or may not include this. Oh, a later English book with selections discussed  is Noneuclidean Tessellations and their Groups by Wilhelm Magnus

Comment: To Ted Shifrin: Are you suggesting writing the u-curve as $$\Big(1,\frac{1}{v_0},\frac{1}{v_0}\Big)+\frac{1}{uv_0-1}\Big(2,v_0+\frac{1}{v_0} ,-v_0+\frac{1}{v_0}\Big),$$ which can be seen as a line when $u$ varies? But then why are we showing the parameter curves are lines? How does it help finding the the $\alpha(u)$ and the function $f(u,v)$ so that $x(u,v)=\alpha(u)+f(u,v) x(u,v_0)$.

Comment: Does checking that the parameter curves are lines part of the verification that the parametrization maps onto the hyperboloid?

Comment: @WillJagy: I worked it out a number of years ago, never having seen it anywhere. I put it as an exercise in my differential geometry notes (which the OP may well be doing). I have recently run across it elsewhere. It basically comes from the fact that the hyperboloid of one sheet is projectively equivalent to the standard saddle surface.

Comment: @user269715: So this *does* show that the $u$-curves are (parts of) lines. You're writing $x(u,v) = \alpha(v) + f(u,v)\beta(v)$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Sorry that I am still a bit confused. If in the above formula, I write $v$ instead of $v_0$, then it will be the hyperboloid but the ruling there is $(2, v+\frac{1}{v},-v+\frac{1}{v})$, which is not a $u$-curve of the form $x(u,v_0)$. Is that what the problem intends? Am I done here, except writing a similar formula by switching the $u$'s and $v$'s and changing a few signs?

Comment: You have to have different representations, as you're suggesting. This one shows that the $u$-curves are lines. You have to redo the algebra and write $x(u,v) = \tilde\alpha(u) + \tilde f(u,v)\tilde\beta(u)$ for different functions $\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta, \tilde f$ to see that the $v$-curves are lines.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: So the problem is asking to show that the hyperboloid is a ruled surface with either parameter curves being its ruling. How does showing that the parameter curves are lines help with that?

Comment: Rulings are lines, by definition. Am I missing something?

Comment: Rulings can be any smooth non-vanishing curves by the definition assumed for the problem. I was thinking I had to find the actual formula to express the parametrization of the hyperboloid as $$\alpha(u)+f(u,v)\cdot \text{(one parameter curve)},$$ so that I could prove that a parameter curve is a ruling of the hyperboloid as a ruled surface.

Comment: No, you're confused about the definition. The *rulings* of a ruled surface are always lines.

Comment: Ted, used your parametrization, a bit revised, for solving $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + z^2$ in integers. Very nice. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842447/solution-of-diophantine-equation/1843184#1843184